# webRTC - Using code example from MDN switch camera doesnt't work at all

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to implement camera switching feature in my webRTC js app. I used the code found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack) at MDN

```
function switchCamera(){
    var switchSender = null;
    var whichCamera = null;
    let switchVideoTrack = null;
    let audioTrack = null;
    var switchCamConstraints = null;
    var switchAudioConstraints = null;
    myPeerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
        if (s.track.kind === "video") {
            switchSender = s;
            switchVideoTrack = s.track;
        }
        
        if (s.track.kind === "audio") {
            audioTrack = s.track;
        }
      });
    if(switchSender){
        // Save existing constraints to be used later
        switchCamConstraints = switchVideoTrack.getConstraints();
        switchAudioConstraints = audioTrack.getConstraints();

        //get current camera mode
        whichCamera = switchCamConstraints.facingMode;

        // Update camera mode
        if (whichCamera == 'user'){
            switchCamConstraints.facingMode = 'environment';
        } else {
            switchCamConstraints.facingMode = 'user';
        }

        //Request camera. with existing(for audio) and updated(for video) constraints
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: {
                switchAudioConstraints
            },
            video: {
                switchCamConstraints
            }
        }).then(function(stream) {
            let newvideoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

              console.log('found sender:', switchSender);

              switchSender.replaceTrack(newvideoTrack);
              console.log('New sender:', switchSender);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                alert(err);
                console.error('Error happens:', err);
            });
    } else {
        //Show an error
        alert('not done');
    }
}
```

I don't see anything change and no error either. But one thing I notice is that if I call that switchcamera function the camera remains still on(the camera light) even after hanging up the call.

Please help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had extra '{' and '}' around the constraints which already had them from `getConstraints()`. The new constraints needed to be passed as `audio: switchAudioConstraints , video: switchCamConstraints` instead of `audio: { switchAudioConstraints } , video: { switchCamConstraints }`